# make bulk action to convert html to pdf with dompdf codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

I have a question. Can I make a bulk action to convert HTML to PDF with [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)?
I have tried this bulk but it doesn't work.

```
function bulk() {
    $action = $this->input->post('action');

    if ($action == "export") {
        $export = $this->input->post('msg');

        for ($i=0; $i < count($export) ; $i++) { 
            $this->load->library('Pdfgenerator');
            $users = $this->model_csv->getDatabyDescription($export[$i]);
            $desc = $users['description'];
            $name =  substr((strrchr($desc, '-')), 2);
            $html = $this->load->view('formulir_new2', $users, true);

            $this->pdfgenerator->generate($html,"E-Tax" . time() . $name);
        }
    }
```

This PDF generator

```
class PdfGenerator {

    public function generate($html,$filename) {
        define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);
        require_once("./vendor/dompdf/dompdf/autoload.inc.php");


        $dompdf = new dompdf();
        $options = new Options();
        $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);

        $dompdf->setOptions($options);
        $dompdf->set_paper(array(0,0, 612, 936), 'portrait');
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf-enter code here>render();
        $dompdf->stream($filename.'.pdf',array("Attachment"=>0));
   }
}
```

here's my single generate

public function export(){
    $data_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

```
$users = $this->model_csv->getDatabyDescription($data_id);
// echo $users['amount'];
$this->load->view('formulir_new2.php', $users);
```

}

```
public function pdf()
{
  $this->load->library('Pdfgenerator');

  $data_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

  $users = $this->model_csv->getDatabyDescription($data_id);


   $desc = $users['description'];
  $name =  substr((strrchr($desc, '-')), 2);


  $html = $this->load->view('formulir_new2', $users, true);

  $this->pdfgenerator->generate($html,"E-Tax" . time() . $name);
}
```

Comment: use `ob_start()` n `ob_end_clean();`

Comment: can you tell me that you can generate single pdf using this code?

Comment: How does it "not work?" Looks like you're trying to stream more than one file at a time, in which case no you can not do that. What, exactly, are you trying to do? Create a collection of PDFs? Create a single PDF out of a collection of HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try This if you able to generate one `pdf` then only this code will help you to generate in bulk.otherwise ignore

```
public function generate($html,$filename)
  {
    ob_start();
    $filename='Ex-'.time().'test.pdf';
    define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);
    require_once("./vendor/dompdf/dompdf/autoload.inc.php");


    $dompdf = new dompdf();
    $options = new Options();
    $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);

    $dompdf->setOptions($options);
    $dompdf->set_paper(array(0,0, 612, 936), 'portrait');
    $html="<html><body>test".rand(0,99)."</body></html>";
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf-enter code here>render();
    $dompdf->stream($filename.'.pdf',array("Attachment"=>0));
    ob_end_clean();
  }
```

Comment: still can't stopped download

Comment: @LukmanHakim can you tell me that by your code can you generate single pdf

Comment: @LukmanHakim i can suggest you that  `$html="<html><body>test".rand(0,99)."</body></html>";` add this line above to `$dompdf->load_html($html);`

Comment: @LukmanHakim so you can able to track where is the problem, and add `ob_start();` and `ob_end_clean();` it will clear your buffer to write new file

Comment: @LukmanHakim you `filename` also incorrect so for to test use any random    name like i used .

Comment: still can't erro Failed to load PDF document.  btw thanks for helping me vijay

Comment: @LukmanHakim you `filename` also incorrect so for to test use any random name like `$filename=rand(0,9999).time().'.pdf';`

Comment: can you give me an example for di code? i'm trully sorry for giving you trouble

Comment: @LukmanHakim one more answer i gave you follow that you will reach your destination, and remember `filenames` should be unique other wise file will orverride by same `filename`

Answer (score 0):

Try This code , put on your controller

```
public function test_pdf(){
    $test_data=array('test1','test2','test3');
    foreach($test_data as $key=>$value){
      $html="<html><body>".$value."</body></html>";
      $this->create_pdf($html,$value);
      //echo "vjiay<br>";
    }
    echo "done";
  }
  public function create_pdf($html,$filename) {
    ob_start();
   // $html = $this->load->view('view_file', $this->data, true);
    $this->load->library('M_pdf');
    ob_end_flush();
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

    $filename .='.pdf' ;//= "test_" . time() . ".pdf";
    //download it D save F.

    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output(FCPATH . 'uploads/' . $filename, "F");
  }
```

Use `MPDF` Library Link `https://github.com/phpclicks/mpdf` download in use

Comment: @LukmanHakim if it use full then please upvote n close your  question